# Why does symlink create an unnecessary "folder"?

Tags: symlink

Say the root folder on my server is /home/bong/www/, so mydomain.com will serve up index.php from /home/bong/www/.

Then I cloned an hg repository and placed it at /home/bong/hg/hgrepo/.

When I am on /home/bong/ I created a symlink as follow so that going to mydomain.com will serve up content from the hg/hgrepo directory:

```
ln -s hg/hgrepo www
```

When I go into www, I see hgrepo -> hg/hgrepo

Problem is then when i go to mydomain.com, it still doesn't work ... but mydomain.com/hgrepo does.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm betting that `www` already existed, so when you created the link, it placed it *inside* the directory that was already there. Solution: delete `www` then create the link again.

Comment: If you are using GNU, then I recommend always using the `-t` or `-T` options with `ln` or `cp` (In this case `-T`). They prevent this type of error. However they are not available on all systems. The problem is that `ln` has 2 forms with 2 arguments. `-T` and `-t` disambiguate this. Note `-t` also reverses the order of the arguments.